# Tool for importing excel spreadsheets

Tags: c#

What's the best tool to import an excel spreadsheet in C# these days? I'm currently using Interop.Excel.dll.

Comment: 'Best' depends on your requirements.

Comment: Are you just reading the file or moving it into a different structure, such as SQL Server or an xml file? SSIS would work well, as long as you are using 32-bit Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jet OLEDB Provider:

```
connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
           "Data Source=c:\somepath\mySpreadsheet.xls;" & _
           "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"""
```

Where `"HDR=Yes"` means that there is a header row in the cell range 
(or named range), so the provider will not include the first row of the
selection into the recordset.

Ref: [how to use ADO to read and write data in Excel workbooks](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;278973)

See also:

- [C# - ASP.NET - Import and Export Excel - What is the best library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444522/c-asp-net-import-and-export-excel-what-is-the-best-library)
- [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c)

Comment: I have just found a funny using Jet:  My column headings are dates, and these get transformed into arbitrary column names like 'F1', 'F2', etc.  I'll comment again if I find a solution.