# Is it possible to use OLEDB to insert a formula?

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb, excel-formula

I have successfully created an Excel file using OLEDB (after first creating a table / sheet).  I would like to insert a formula that sums a Cost (Currency) cell but have been unable find any techniques for doing so.

I have tried inserting the formula into the Cost field as follows but receive an invalid data type error, which is understandable:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("P0", OleDbType.PropVariant).Value = "=SUM(K2:K5)"
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO  [" & ExcelTableName & "] (Cost) VALUES(P0);"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Is there any way of doing this using OLEDB or will I need to use automation?

Comment: Perhaps this may help: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1051

Comment: [Jet only provides data integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624012/microsft-jet-oledb-connection-to-excel-loses-formulae).
So it is not possible to insert formula.

Comment: That is what I suspected. Thanks!

Comment: It is possible but not the way you're trying to do it, see my answer

Comment: @Alexander, I agree with your comment. If you care to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: it **IS POSSIBLE TO INSERT A FORMULA** so long as you put the formula as a column in your query, then use Excel's *CopyFromRecordset* method - **I HAVE DONE THIS MANY MANY TIMES IN THE PAST**

Answer (score 0):

you could use a SQL Query that includes the formula in a column, and in Excel use an ADO DB Recordset to execute the query.

Then you would use the **CopyFromRecordset** method on the *range* object to dump your resultset into Excel which would include the formula.

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
sQry="Select fields, '=IF(A:A>=B:B, ''''Good'''', ''''Bad'''') from table where criteria'
xlApp.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset oRs
```

this can also be done from .NET, just differently...

see [MSDN Library: Transfer data to a worksheet by using ADO.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306022)