# What .NET library can I use to generate Excel(XLS) file without installed Excel?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, file

Are there any free libraries I can use to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import and Export Excel - What is the best library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444522/import-and-export-excel-what-is-the-best-library)

Comment: @Hans - very much so. there are lots. Its high time they got cleaned up and wiki'ed.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this tool with good results
http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

NPOI  -- it's in development now -- but I think Excel is the first use case.

http://npoi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the answers on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444522/import-and-export-excel-what-is-the-best-library). They might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple save as .CSV (with commat separated values of course).

Comment: It has to be user friendly formatted. Even pictires will be added there.

Comment: how did this answer get two votes? Does it answer the question at all?

Comment: @Anonymous Tripe, you are missing an important point: The correct answer to a question is reached in stages - and all answers that contribute towards the final accepted response deserve votes. The question (while mentitioning .xls files) did not specify that Excel objects - other than data - had to be saved. It was responses such as mine that contributed to a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: It mentioned the format XLS specifically, so your answer is wrong from that point of view. Making assumptions about the persons requirements, because you are aware of a better, cleaner, whatever approach is missing the point. In fact you are redefining the problem as opposed to clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [CarlosAg Excel Xml Writer Library](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/). Works as advertised and has a lot of options.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries/4076407#4076407) out for a good place to find out about all sorts of usefull .net libraries:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries/4076407#4076407

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. If you can output xslx instead of xsl investigate the xslx format as it's just a bunch of xmls archived together in a zip. You can generate those pretty easily using the various xml tools available in .NET
2. Generate a csv with xsl extension if all you want to export is data
3. If you need some basic formatting included in the exported file excel is able to open HTML  tags with their containing tr/td. You can set style values (colors, fonts etc.) to those and excel will render them properly. Same strategy as point 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but you can try the Excel library from Infragistics [here](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/infragisticsexcel.aspx). It handles importing/exporting, formula solving, formatting of cells and strings, and a lot of other things in these formats: XLS, XLT, XLSX, XLTX, XLSM, XLTM.

Note: I work for Infragistics.

Comment: Note: This question says free.

Comment: I understand. That is why I prefaced my answer with "It's not free, but...".  I thought this might be helpful for people who are willing to spend money and they search online and come across this thread.

Answer (score 0):

For production grade Excel file generation, you can use:

1. OpenXML SDK for Excel 2007 and above format:
   http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124
   http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/14/p/732/1816.aspx
2. SpreadsheetGear
3. Aspose.Cells for .Net

(You can google for the links)

Cheers,

Ajit Singh