# Updating Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I add new values to an uploaded `application/vnd.ms-excel` file in C#?
Can anybody help?

Comment: You need a managed Excel library.  I don't know of any free ones.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444522/import-and-export-excel-what-is-the-best-library

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Excel 2007/2010 you can make use of Microsoft's added XML standard with various third party libraries.

I've used EPPlus in the past, but its license dictates if you release your project to the public you must release its source as well.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

For that reason I've used ClosedXML to manipulate excel files (.xlsx and .xlsm). You open workbooks from a disk location, or from a filestream.

http://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: EPPlus' license has been changed to LGPL as of Jan 31, 2012 (v 3.0.0.2).