# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel not registered DLL

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, office-2013, vba

using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` leads to the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component
>   with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the
>   following error: 80040154 Klasse nicht registriert (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

The error occures in the fourth line of this code:

```
 using EX = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

 private void LoopBANFDokumenteLibrary(System.Uri Link)
 {
        EX.Application MSExcel = new EX.Application();
        EX.Workbook WB = MSExcel.Workbooks.Add(new EX.Workbook()); //ERROR: Exception thrown
        EX.Worksheet WS = WB.Worksheets.Add(new EX.Worksheet());
        /*...and further code...*/
 }
```

Some years ago, I used this Interop.Excel.DLL daily and a never had this problem. Opening regedit.exe, the dll is registered as you can see on this screenshot:

[image: regedit]

Does anybody has an idea, whats wrong?

Regards and thank you,
Jan

Comment: That error generall indicates Excel isn't installed...

Comment: I'm currently running it :-)

Comment: .. could it be a version mismatch?

Comment: `EX.Workbook WB = MSExcel.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);` and ditto for adding the WorkSheet, passing `new EX.XXX()` is not valid, there is no such overload in the interface.

Comment: This error can also occur when your application is of a different "bitness" than your Office installation. When you're using 32bit Office then your application must be compiled / run as 32bit, otherwise when you're using the 64bit Office then your application must be compiled / run as 64bit.

Comment: Related (but not sure it's a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/13660938/3775798

Comment: Try : EX.Workbook WB = (_Workbook)MSExcel.Workbooks.AddXlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
EX.Workbook WB = MSExcel.Workbooks.Add(new EX.Workbook());
```

to

```
EX.Workbook WB = MSExcel.Workbooks.Add();
```

Similarly use

```
EX.Worksheet WS = WB.Worksheets.Add();
```