# Excel.Application Exception

Tags: c#, excel

In main part of application I call this line:

```
Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
```

It give me an exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'
```

I tried to run debug in x86, x64 modes is the same result.

[image]

Comment: Is Excel installed on this machine?

Comment: Yes, and I have imported this using `Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Comment: The error message indicates that Excel is not installed.  Note that having the Excel Interop assembly is not enough; you also need Excel to be installed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660938/com-exception-80040154-when-creating-an-excel-application   If Excel really is installed, try reinstalling or repairing the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring them like this, fully qualified:

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

```
                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
```