# Reading cell with format from excel in c#

Tags: asp.net, excel

There is requirement of Excel file upload on .aspx page and reading data and store that in database.  In the excel user can format specific word or sentence in a any cell.  We want preserve those formatting in form of HTML tag.  So we want to reach data with formatting with html tag.  How it can be achieved.

Comment: You could try changing it to a csv file and reading that for the database values.

Answer (score 1):

Probaly the best way would be to use the Excel interop assemblies under Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace. The code would be something like this:

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = ExcelApp.ActiveSheet;
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
   for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++){
       Excel.Range currentCell = activeWorksheet.Cells[i, j];
       // formating 
       var fontFamily = currentCell.Font.Name;
       var italics = currentCell.Font.Italic;
       var color = currentCell.Font.Color;
   }
}
```

This opens an excel file and loops trough first 99 rows and columns.

But this could be too intensive since it would open Excel for each document - not sure what kind of performance is required. There are other libraries available that offer simple reading and writing to Excel, but I'm not sure if they offer reading the formats and things like that. You can find some more info about those tools here: [Import and export excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444522/import-and-export-excel-what-is-the-best-library?rq=1). I just checked and it seems [EPPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) support cell styling, so that might be an alternative.

Comment: Agree about EPPlus it's much faster and more flexible in my opinion.