# Read first column of TXT or CSV or XLS or XLSX

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsx, xls

I need to parse the first column of a document into a list `['item1', 'item2', ...]`, and this document can be:

- a TXT document (items separated by newlines)
- a CSV document with one single column (then it's similar to TXT document)
- a CSV with many columns, separated by `;`
- a CSV with many columns, separated by `,`
- a XLS with one or many columns
- a XLSX with one or many columns

I was about to code it with many cases:

```
ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1].lower()
if ext == '.txt':
    with open(f, 'r') as f:
        L = f.read().splitlines()
if ext == '.csv':
    reader = csv.reader(...)
    ...
if ext == '.xls':
    ...
```

but **is there a general higher-level tool in Python that does all of this directly?**

Comment: There are a lot of import/export libraries available online. I found [this Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444522/import-and-export-excel-what-is-the-best-library) in particular to be pretty interesting,albeit it's for C#, generally the same principles apply.

Comment: You could take a look at the [`pyexcel`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel/) library.

Comment: @MartinEvans, this looks interesting. There are many variations: `pyexcel-io`, `pyexcel-xls`, etc. Would you want to post an answer with it?

Answer (score 1):

The [pyexcel](https://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel/) library is such a high level abstraction for needing to deal with data files in different formats using a consistent interface:

> **pyexcel** provides **one** application programming interface to read,
>   manipulate and write data in different excel formats. This library
>   makes information processing involving excel files an enjoyable task.
>   The data in excel files can be turned into array or dict with least
>   code, vice versa. This library focuses on data processing using excel
>   files as storage media hence fonts, colors and charts were not and
>   will not be considered.

A simple example usage is given as:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> records = pe.iget_records(file_name="your_file.xls")
>>> for record in records:
...     print("%s is aged at %d" % (record['Name'], record['Age']))
```